# strict order property

Tags: group-theory, logic, order-theory, model-theory, abelian-groups

I wanted to prove that the theory of ordered abelian group has a strict order property.
I know by the theory of Kikyo and Shellah we have:

a theory is unstable iff it has SOP or NIP

and by the :
https://www.jstor.org/stable/1999281?seq=1

the ordered abelian group does not have IP but is there any way to prove SOP directly?

Comment: I think you meant to write: a theory is unstable iff it has SOP or IP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is immediate from the definition that the formula $x\leq y$ witnesses SOP in the theory of ordered abelian groups. For example, in $\mathbb{Z}$, look at the family of sets defined by $x\leq n$ for various $n$. These sets form an infinite chain of proper containments.

In  fact, the definition of SOP is a *direct generalization* of the property of having a definable linear order (which is infinite in some model). More precisely, a theory has SOP iff it has a definable preorder with infinite strict chains (in some model).

Also, a correction. You wrote "I know by the theory of Kikyo and Shellah we have:"

> A theory is unstable iff it has SOP or NIP

This is a theorem of Shelah. It appeared in *Classification  Theory* in 1978. There is also a well-known theorem of Kikyo and Shelah (which appeared in [their only joint paper](https://doi.org/10.2178/jsl/1190150038), in 2002), but that theorem says that if $T$ is an SOP theory, then the theory of models of  $T$ expanded by an automorphism has no model companion.

Comment: Nice answer, but I think you should qualify the last paragraph: the atomless Boolean algebras do have generic automorphisms (well, the countable one does, I'm not entirely sure about what the corresponding definition would be for the uncountable ones, but I'm sure there's a sensible one).

Comment: @tomasz Thanks. I meant "generic automorphism" (for a theory $T$) in the sense of a model companion for $T_\sigma$, but you're absolutely right that this is ambiguous.

Comment: @AlexKruckman actually I am trying to understand why we can not prove the theory of increasing differential ordered abelian groups has model companion and QE in the order of that I was reading a paper by Kushnik pal, actually, I wanted to understand the Kikyo and Shellah theorem then because the ordered abelian group has SOP, we have to put restrictions on the automorphism in the case to find model companion. and the restriction will create the multiplicative difference ordered abelian groups. but I could not find any proof for the SOP of ordered abelian groups.

Comment: @AlexKruckman  In addition, I know that the \mathbb{Z}[\sigma]-module are the models of increasing differential ordered abelian groups but I found a paper by Chernikov(https://www.math.ucla.edu/~chernikov/teaching/StabilityTheory285D/StabilityNotes.pdf)(example 2.48 number (2))
the modules are stable. so by the theorem, I mentioned above: a theory is unstable iff it has SOP or NIP. I was confused whether the whole statement is correct or not.

Comment: @bahar It's not clear what you mean by "are" when you say "$\mathbb{Z}[\sigma]$-modules are the models of increasing differential ordered abelian groups". But I think I can explain your confusion. For any ring $R$, the theory of $R$-modules is a theory in the language $\{+,-,0\}\cup \{r\mid r\in R\}$, where $r$ is a unary function symbol for multiplication by $r$. Note that there is no order in the language! This theory is always stable. On the other hand, whatever an increasing differential ordered abelian group is, it probably has the ordering $\leq$ in the language, so it obviously has SOP.

Answer (score 1):

If you know about imaginary elements, it is not very difficult to see that the strict order property of $T$ is exactly equivalent to the existence of a $T^{\mathrm{eq}}$-definable partial order with an infinite chain (in a saturated model; in an arbitrary model, there may not be an infinite chain, but there are arbitrarily long finite chains).

In particular, if $T$ defines a partial order with an infinite chain, it has SOP, and in particular, if it defines an infinite *linear* order with an infinite chain, then it has the SOP.

All this follows from considering the formulas $x\leq p$, where $p$ is an element of the infinite chain.

The ordered abelian groups have an infinite linear order built in, so they certainly do have the SOP.